# pointer-events: none on li not working on edge?

Tags: css

Im testing on IE Edge. This is my css code:

```
li.inactive{
    pointer-events: none;
    background: #ccc;
    -webkit-filter: none;
    filter:none;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    h1{
        background: #eee;
        color: #ccc;
        span{
            color: #ccc;
        }
        i{
            color: #ccc;
        }
    }
    h1:after{
        border-color: transparent transparent transparent #eee;

    }
}
```

On chrome its working but on i can hover over h1 and click on li. Any suggestion how can i fix that?

Comment: Is it not any of the known issues listed in http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events ? (linked to the css display property). Also, you cannot nest CSS declarations

Comment: @Simon, it does say that pointer-events does not work in IE11 and Edge, unless the element is set to block or inline-block (which a li-element isn't as standard)

Comment: im using scss...

Comment: you can't have `h1-h6`  inside a `li`

Answer (score 4):

`pointer-event` does not work on links in IE11 and Edge unless display is set to `block` or `inline-block`. [Source](https://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events)

A li-item is neither `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;`, unless it is specified, so to fix the issue, try this:

```
li.inactive{
    display:block;
    pointer-events: none;
    background: #ccc;
    -webkit-filter: none;
    filter:none;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    h1{
        background: #eee;
        color: #ccc;
        span{
            color: #ccc;
        }
        i{
            color: #ccc;
        }
    }
    h1:after{
        border-color: transparent transparent transparent #eee;

    }
}
```

Comment: i added display:block on li but still i can click and hover over h1

Comment: This worked for me as pointer events: none on IE was letting click the element. By changing the li as block element, the pointer event worked.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `diplay: inline-block;` to your CSS class.

Check here:
https://codepen.io/ymana/pen/yGWPWw